# Merchandising using Custom Sort Fields in ElasticSearch

Tags: sorting, mapping, elasticsearch

My company would like to merchandise search results by manually specifying the first several search results followed by all remaining search results sorted by some other criteria.

One solution is to create a new numeric field on all the records we want to appear first, and omit it from the other records and then sort on that field with missing values last.

But this requires creating a new field for every merchandised search. Will search become inefficient if there are hundreds or even thousands of fields in the index mapping that only apply to a few records?

Is there another solution to this problem that we haven't thought of?

Answer (score 0):

I'm honestly not sure how ES would react to that many fields...but it sounds a little scary.

How about creating a single field `merchandised_search`, and then performing a [constant_filters_score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html)  boost on any document that matches a term filter?

If you make the boost large enough, the docs matching the filter will automatically sort to the top of the list, while everything else sorts normally.  You can make different merchandised searches by simply using a different value in `merchandised_search`.  And filters are fast, so it shouldn't hurt your performance too much.

Something like this:

```
{
   "custom_filters_score" : {
       "query" : {
           "match" : {"field1" : "test text to query"}
       },
       "filters" : [
            {
               "filter" : { "term" : { "merchandised_search" : "search1" } },
               "boost" : "10"
            }
       ],
       "score_mode" : "first"
   }
}
```

Comment: Will this let me control the ordering of the results, or will it just ensure that records with the term in the merchandised_search come back before those that don't have it?

Comment: You can control the ordering of the entire recordset e.g. sort by score descending, and name ascending.  But you won't be able to sort the "merchandised search" results differently than the "regular" search results using this method.